# PyPDF2 writes corrupt file

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, pypdf

Having some issues w/ PyPDF2 - specifically in splitting and rewriting files!

I am opening a file on **my ubuntu server**, splitting it into individual pages (max 3), and **writing to the file system** (then putting to S3). An **error is not thrown** when writing the file, but I cannot open it when downloading from S3 and, as you'll see below, cannot open on server.

Any ideas?

```
  inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(fi, 'rb'))

  print('breaking file into %s pages' % inputpdf.numPages) # 17 pages

       for i in range(min(3,inputpdf.numPages)):
            output = PdfFileWriter()
            output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
            new_fi = fi[:-4]+'_page_%s.pdf' % i # fi = ./deals/temp_files/test_experian.pdf
            with open(new_fi, 'wb') as outputStream:
                 output.write(outputStream) # successfully writes all files
                 pdf_check = open(new_fi, 'rb')
                 print('opened PDF')
                 read_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_check) # "error throw -> EOF market not found"
                 print('loaded PDF')
                 page_content = read_pdf.getPage(0).extractText()
                 print(page_content.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason for Error:
Attempt to read a file in write mode
Solution:

```
 for i in range(min(3,inputpdf.numPages)):
     output = PdfFileWriter()
     output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
     new_fi = fi[:-4]+'_page_%s.pdf' % i
     with open(new_fi, 'wb') as outputStream:
         output.write(outputStream)
     pdf_check = open(new_fi, 'rb')
     print('opened PDF')
     read_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_check)
     print('loaded PDF')
     page_content = read_pdf.getPage(0).extractText()
     print(page_content.encode('utf-8'))
```

By using

```
with open(new_fi, 'wb') as outputStream
```

you create a file pointer in write mode.
The file is only closed at the end of that 'with' block by default.
Hence when you tried reading, read_pdf gives an error as the file wasn't closed before opening it to read again.